# Adding variables on a line Bash

Tags: bash, file, addition

I have a file like this:

```
Dave 10 20 55
Kate 17 12 1 399
Simon 9 209 1 55 5
Charles 1 2
```

How do I add these numbers together for each person line by line, with it also working for different amounts of numbers?

So the output would be like this:

```
Dave 85
Kate 429
etc.
```

Any direction would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: What output do you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: Basically I want the output to be their name and the calculated sum of the numbers after their name. Basically I have no idea where to start so any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a good use-case for AWK.

Comment: Sounds like an even better use-case for the [basic calculator (bc)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_%28programming_language%29) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a Bash-only solution:

```
while read a b ; do echo "${a} "$(( ${b// /+} )) ; done < numbers.txt
```

or, expanded:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read name numbers
do
  echo -n "${name} "
  echo $(( ${numbers// /+} ))
done < numbers.txt
```

This uses Bash's pattern substitution during parameter expansion to replace blanks with `+`, and arithmetic expansion to calculate the sum.

Comment: An up-vote for elegance, though it's worth noting that any line-by-line bash loop will be slow for large files (an `awk` solution will be much faster). Your _other_ answer is therefore the worst of both worlds: a bash loop that calls multiple external utilities in each iteration.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks! Of course you are right. But even for 10,000 records, this script takes below 500 ms on my machine. The other one is rather slow as you said with almost 14 s, but if requirements permit e.g. because there are never more than 100 people, I would still recommend it for readability. I'll add a little performance note there.

Comment: Great, thank you for your insight, how do I go about executing this code? do I input the lines in the terminal line by line?

Comment: @BarneyChambers: Copy the first (one-line) snippet into your terminal, correct the name of the input file, then submit.

Comment: Hey mklement0, I'm getting an "Illegal variable name" error, ill have to do some digging, thanks for your help

Comment: @BarneyChambers Is it possible that you are using `csh` instead of Bash (your question was tagged "bash")? The one-liner should work in an interactive Bash with only the input file changed. Alternatively you can copy the multi-line script into a new `script.sh` and run it with `bash script.sh`.

Comment: Good catch re `csh`, but I just realized that the one-liner is also missing 2 `;` to be syntactically correct and also doesn't output a terminating `\n` in each iteration. @BarneyChambers: Open a `bash` terminal window and use the following: `while read a b; do printf '%s %s\n'  "${a} "$(( ${b// /+} )); done < numbers.txt`

Comment: @mklement0: Ouch, yes. Fixed and retested^Wtested.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have it working now, I will post my solution soon

Answer (score 1):

This kind of task is what AWK is really made for.

The following script – optimized for readability, not minimum number of characters – would do what you have asked for.

```
/^[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+)*[[:space:]]*$/ {
    name = $1;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sum += $i;
    }
    printf("%s %d\n", name, sum);
}
```

If you save the script as `script.awk` and your data is in a file named `data.txt`, you can run `awk -f script.awk data.txt` and get the result written to standard output.

The logic in the above script is pretty straight forward if you know the basics of AWK.  If you don't, I recommend reading [*The GNU Awk User’s Guide*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html).  In a nutshell: `^[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+)*[[:space:]]*$` is a regular expression ([using POSIX character classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html)) that matches a name followed by zero or more numbers.  If that pattern is matched, the rule is activated and iterates over all but the first field in the record, summing them up.  Finally, the result is printed via the familiar `printf`.

If you want to write a single shell script, you can inline the AWK script like so:

```sh
awk '
  # Here goes the AWK script...
  # It cannot contain a single quote in this case.
' data.txt
```

Comment: Nice, but given that the OP doesn't mention a specific platform, it's better to remain portable, which means not to assume support for `\s` and use `[[:space:]]` instead. Similarly, `[[:alpha:]]` is not only shorter, but would also cover foreign chars. such as 'ü' (except, regrettably, in BSD awk).

Comment: @mklement0 Good point, I have edited the regex.  It's always a good idea to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Awk program. Awk automatically loops through all lines in your file. I added an inner `for` loop to loop through each *field* in each line. Since each line has a different number of fields I use the `NF` variable which is the number of fields on each line. `$1` refers to the first field (the name). The `for` loops from field #2 to the last field. Using `$num` instead of `num` refers to the *value* of that field:

```
awk '{
    printf $1 "   "
    sum = 0
    for ( num = 2; num <= NF; num++ ) {
        sum += $num
    }
    print sum
}' file.txt
```

This prints out:

```
Dave   85
Kate   429
Simon   279
Charles   3
```

It shouldn't be too hard to get everything to line up.

Answer (score 0):

This simple approach uses Bash, `tr` and `bc` (assuming your file is called `numbers.txt`):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read name numbers
do
  echo -n "${name} "
  tr " " "+" <<< "$numbers" | bc
done < numbers.txt
```

Each line is separated into `name` and `numbers`. After printing `name`, the blanks are replaced by `+` with `tr`, then piped to `bc` to calculate the sum for that line.

And as a one-liner:

```
while read a b ; do echo -n "${a} " ; tr " " + <<<"$b" | bc ; done < numbers.txt
```

*Note:* This solution is rather slow for large input files because it calls multiple external programs per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is very good in doing such calculation. Here is another awk solution.

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$1]+=$i}END{for(j in a)print j, a[j]}' input.txt 
Charles 3
Dave 85
Simon 279
Kate 429
```

Comment: Since the OP states "add […] together line by line", it's fair to assume that each line can be summed up _individually_. Your solution sums up across lines that share the same 1st field, which is a potentially different use case. If there are no duplicate names in the input data, your result is _basically_ the same, but given that you use `<key> in <array>` to enumerate the array, the input order is not preserved, as evidenced by your sample output.